# sharepoint new item form with multiple submit button + sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I am having 150 columns grouped in to 10 groups in a single new form.

I want to submit first group and update the next groups individually in a single form with individual save buttons.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.